# How to start coroutines and continue with synchronous tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand `asyncio` and port my undestanding of `threading`. I will take the example of two threads running indefinitely and a non-threaded loop (all of them outputting to the console).

The `threading` version is

```
import threading
import time

def a():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('a')

def b():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print('b')

threading.Thread(target=a).start()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('c')
```

I now tried to port this to `asyncio` based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#tasks-and-coroutines).

**Problem 1**: I do not understand how to add the non-threaded task as all examples I saw show an ongoing loop at the end of the program which governs the `asyncio` threads.

I then wanted to have at least the two first threads (`a` and `b`) running in parallel (and, worst case, add the third `c` as a thread as well, abandonning the idea of mixed thread and non-threded operations):

```
import asyncio
import time

async def a():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('a')

async def b():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('b')

async def mainloop():
    await a()
    await b()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(mainloop())
loop.close()
```

**Problem 2**: The output is a sequence of `a`, suggering that the `b()` coroutine is not called at all. Isn't `await` supposed to start `a()` and come back to the execution (and then start `b()`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` stops execution at a point, you do `await a()`, and you have an infinite loop in `a()`, so it's logical `b()` doesn't get called. Think about it as if you insert `a()` in `mainloop()`.

Consider this example:

```
async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('in')

    print('out (never gets printed)')
```

To achieve what you want you need to create a future which would manage multiple coroutines. `asyncio.gather` is for that.

```
import asyncio


async def a():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('a')


async def b():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('b')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(a(), b())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Danil. If I get it right, I therefore have to start all my coroutines at the same time (via `.gather()`) and what was possible with `threading` (start a thread, do something, start another thread, ...) is not possible anymore with  ` asyncio` ?

Comment: Sure, I already upvoted it, waiting a bit in hope that there could be a solution for the separated start of coroutines, otherwise yours is great, thanks.